# How Can I Call this Nested JSON with the JSON Array in Android Java

Tags: java, android, json

I want to filter out only one cinemax , from the JSON below without a repetition , am using a RecyclerView to fetch Data , but it repeats the Cinemax .How can i filter out one Cinemax without neglecting other Nested Data.

```
[{"Cinemax":"Metrop Cinemax","Contacts":"0704594180",
"Movie":[{"MovieName":"Ice Age 3","ShowTime":{"Monday":"1:30 p.m , 3:40 p.m",
"Tuesday":"1:30 pm , 3:40 p.m","Wednesday":"1:30 p.m., 3:40 p.m","Thursday":"1:30 p.m., 3:40 p.m",
"Friday":"1:30 p.m., 3:40 p.m","Saturday":"1:30 p.m., 3:40 p.m","Sunday":"1:30 p.m., 3:40 p.m"},
"Synopsis":"Manny, Diego and sid","photo":"ice_age_3.jpg","others":null}]},
{"Cinemax":"Metrop Cinemax","Contacts":"0704594180",
"Movie":[{"MovieName":"Zootopia","ShowTime":{"Monday":"4:30 p.m , 6:30 p.m","Tuesday":"4:30 p.m , 6:30 p.m",
"Wednesday":"4:30 p.m , 6:30 p.m","Thursday":"4:30 p.m , 6:30 p.m","Friday":"4:30 p.m , 6:30 p.m",
"Saturday":"4:30 p.m , 6:30 p.m","Sunday":"4:30 p.m , 6:30 p.m"},
"Synopsis":"Manny, Diego and sid","photo":"zootopia.jpg","others":null}]}
{"Cinemax":"Huxy Cinemax","Contacts":"0704594180",
"Movie":[{"MovieName":"Zootopia","ShowTime":{"Monday":"4:30 p.m , 6:30 p.m","Tuesday":"4:30 p.m , 6:30 p.m",
"Wednesday":"4:30 p.m , 6:30 p.m","Thursday":"4:30 p.m , 6:30 p.m","Friday":"4:30 p.m , 6:30 p.m",
"Saturday":"4:30 p.m , 6:30 p.m","Sunday":"4:30 p.m , 6:30 p.m"},
"Synopsis":"Manny, Diego and sid","photo":"zootopia.jpg","others":null}]}
```

This is my Method Am using in Java

```
private void parseResult(String result) {
        try {

            JSONArray ar = new JSONArray(result);

            feedsList = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i = 0; i < ar.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject obj = ar.getJSONObject(i);
                ItemObjects item = new ItemObjects();

                item.setCinemaName(obj.optString("CinemaName"));
                item.setContact(obj.optString("Contacts"));
                item.setMovieName(obj.optString("MovieName"));
                item.setMonday(obj.optString("Monday"));
                item.setCinemaxPhoto(obj.optString("Tuesday"));
                .
                .
                .  item.setSynopsis(obj.optString("Synopsis"));
                item.setPhoto(obj.optString("photo"));

                feedsList.add(item);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: On which criteria do you want to filter?

Comment: When am parsing for the first List in RecyclerView , i want Only Lists of the Cinemax without repeating themselves (Filtering Repeatations of Cinemax), , then after clicking on one of them ,inside then i Get all the Movies and relevant information of The Cinemax @Prerak Sola

Comment: Search for `ExpandableListView`. It's the thing that you want.

Comment: Not exactly , i dont want the `ExpandableListView`, But atleast your idea worked, the problem was on  a JSON Array handling (Nested JSON)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  private void parseResult(String result) {
    try {

        JSONArray ar = new JSONArray(result);

        feedsList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < ar.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject obj = ar.getJSONObject(i);
            ItemObjects item = new ItemObjects();

            item.setCinemaName(obj.optString("CinemaName"));
            item.setContact(obj.optString("Contacts"));

            //Here you have another Movie Json Array so get it in JSONArray
            JSONArray movieArray =obj.getJSONArray("Movie");

            //get the first object of Movie  JSONArray and use it.
            JSONObject movieObject=movieArray.getJSONObject(0);


            item.setMovieName(movieObject.optString("MovieName"));


            //This JSOn object to get SHOWTIME object
            JSONObject showTime=movieObject.getJSONObject("ShowTime");

            item.setMonday(showTime.optString("Monday"));
            item.setCinemaxPhoto(showTime.optString("Tuesday"));

            item.setSynopsis(movieObject.optString("Synopsis"));
            item.setPhoto(movieObject.optString("photo"));

            feedsList.add(item);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```